# Intellij can't find SDK for module sometimes

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am having difficulties with intellij idea IDE. I am having a project with multiple modules. One of modules is "Main" and it has a class Main and method inside that class which calls, depending on some input data, one of two modules( Console and UI). 
Whenever I run project for first time after booting everything works. Second time I get error 'Cannot find SDK('12') for module UI'. 
I added second SDK in intellij from same folder as the first one and it is called '12(02)'. If I change SDK for module 'UI' and run project, everything works for one running. For next to work I have to switch SDK once again. 
Doing this on freshly installed win10 with jdk12 and new intellij.
How to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to

- Menu - Build - Rebuild project
- Reimport for a build tool (maven/gradle/ant), I guess right click on a config file like .pom might help.
- Check all settings about Java environment in settings File - Setting - *search Java"

If nothing to help delete .idea folder and .iml file and reopen a project.

Comment: When I try to rebuild, error keeps showing. And I don't use any of build tools for project, and it is made from beginning on this setup and in intellij